# regular expression for finding the roman letters while considering a white space in python

Tags: python, regex

I write a python code for finding the roman letters, this code identifies the roman letters but there is a problem.

Code is

```
file="C:/Python26/test.txt";
f=open("romans.txt",'w');
pattern ='^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$';
with open(file,'r') as rf:
    lines = rf.readlines();
    c=0;
    for word in lines:
        if re.match(pattern, word):
            f.write(word.strip("\n")+"\t"'1'"\n");
            c=c+1;
        else:
            f.write(word.strip("\n")+"\t"'0'"\n");
            c=c+1;
        print c;
    f.close();
```

**Actually my data is in the form like this** (Filename "romans.txt"):

```
Src
mAB
32DC32
P50
The
activation
fan
**.**

II
III
IV
NFKappaB
IL23RE
cat
the
VIII
a
an
**.**
```

**but my output is like this**

```
Src       0
mAB       0
32DC32    0
P50       0
The       0
activation  0
fan 0
.   0
    1
II  1
III 1
IV  1
NFKappaB    0
IL23RE  0
cat 0
the 0
VIII    1
a   0
an  0
.   0
```

The code gave the tag "1" to white space instead of "0".

Answer (score 3):

In your original regex:

```
^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$
   ^           ^  ^            ^  ^            ^  ^
```

All the elements are optional (marked with `^`), so an empty string will match.

You can use a negative lookahead to exclude this case:

```
^(?!$)M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$
```

[Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/iJ8oV2/1)

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the blank line and skip your regular expression check:

```
if len(word.strip()):
   # your regular expression logic
else:
   print(word)
```